# PiezoActuator energy loss in a fluidic environment

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, frequency, piezoelectric

I am trying to model the loss of a Piezo actuator in a fluidic environment.

A Piezo actuator can be modeled using a Equivalent Circuit model stated below.

http://www.noliac.com/typo3temp/GB/csm_Electromechanic_coupling-01_593217e456_38592aa773.jpg

RLC elements represent the mass-spring-damper units to model the resonances of a Piezo actuator.

However I am trying to look at the Frequency Response of the Impedance of this model. Does the phase of this impedance tell me something about the energy losses in this system?

Comment: yes, it does: for small losses the dissipation is proportional to the group delay of a minimum phase system.

Comment: Thanks. However can you elaborate on that a bit more? Should I worry about large or small signals? Hysteresis of the Piezo?

Comment: I cannot help with the problem of nonlinearity, large or small signals, etc.,  that is a very different question. You original question was about phase and energy loss. Phase itself does not matter but phase (group, envelope) delay, ie., the derivative of phase wrt frequency does. Intuitively the larger the group delay is the more time the signal spends in the resonator and the more the resonator dissipates.

Answer (score 0):

We start with a minimum phase transfer function of complex frequency of $s=\sigma + \mathfrak{j}\omega$, say $H(s)$, namely one that has no zeros or poles in the right half plane. In other words $\textrm{ln}H(s) = A(s)+\mathfrak{j} B(s)$ is holomorphic on $\Re {s} = \sigma>0$. Here $A(\mathfrak{j}\omega)$ is the insertion gain (insertion loss, attenuation) function measured in nepers and $B(\mathfrak{j}\omega)$ is the phase advance (phase delay) both taken as functions of the *real* frequency $\omega$.

Now consider a lossless system, one that is constructed from ideal inductors and capacitors and add dissipation *uniformly* to its elements, that is replace all ideal inductors with a series connected inductor and resistor so that $\delta=R/L$ is constant, and replace all ideal capacitors with a parallel connection of  a capacitor and conductance so that $G/C$ is also the *same* $\delta$ constant as is for the inductors. Now one can show that this results in replacing the transfer function $H(s)$ by $H(s+\delta)$, and of course the same for its logarithm. Therefore, we have for uniform and small losses that

$$\textrm{ln}H(s+\delta) = A(s+\delta)+\mathfrak{j} B(s+\delta)\\
\approx A(s) + \delta \frac{A(s)}{ds}+\mathfrak{j}B(s) + \mathfrak{j}\delta \frac{B(s)}{ds}$$
Now calculate this on the *real* frequency axis, that is for $s=\mathfrak{j}\omega$, then

$$\textrm{ln}H(\mathfrak{j}\omega+\delta) \\
\approx \textrm{ln}H(\mathfrak{j}\omega) - \mathfrak{j}\delta \frac{A(\mathfrak{j}\omega)}{d\omega}+ \delta \frac{B(\mathfrak{j}\omega)}{d\omega}$$

Note that both $A(\mathfrak{j}\omega)$ and $B(\mathfrak{j}\omega)$ are *real* functions of the frequency $\omega$. The increase of the insertion loss is therefore the term $\delta \frac{B(\mathfrak{j}\omega)}{d\omega}$ where the derivative $\tau(\omega)=-\frac{B(\mathfrak{j}\omega)}{d\omega}$ is the group delay. (The negative sign is conventional and for well-behaved narrow-band low loss systems will give a *positive* delay.)

Comment: Highly interesting! As for the losses from a pure inductor and capacitor, i replace them with a complex inductor and capacitor.